# How to unit test Azure Functions in Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio, azure-functions, azure-functions-core-tools

I am using Visual Studio to create Azure Functions. I can create, publish and run functions manually. If I set my Function project to Start Up and run, I host starts. How do I get the Host to start when using MSTest ?

I want to write a test using RestSharp and invoke the functions during the tests - the way the actual applicaion will work. It seems I need a way to get MSTest to start the Azure Function Host.

Comment: Why do you need to run the function to unit test it?

Comment: While I found it possible to run tests without running the function i.e. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-test-a-function  I can't figure out how to invoke the tests using RestSharp unless they they are actually running in a host. Without a tested RestSharp implementation, I can't really know how what the correct invocation looks like. We used to be able to do something like this in the older VS test frameworks with Asp.Net

Comment: Why do you need to use RestSharp to test them also?

Comment: Because that is how I am using them

Comment: Is there a better way ?

Comment: If you post your Azure function code, I can show you a way I've unit tested an Azure function before.

Comment: Are you referring to something like:  var response = (OkObjectResult)await MyFunction.Run(request, logger)

Comment: Similar, yes. What is wrong with that approach?

Comment: When code the consumer app and try to use RestSharp, I find myself trying to figure out how to Invoke. It is time consuming. By working out the invocation logic in UnitTests, it becomes a simple copy/edit operation to invoke the function in app.

Comment: I would say that's not really what a unit test is for?

Comment: I am not really a purist, more pragmatic. Call it an Integration test

Comment: Have you read the doc:https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-test-a-function?

Answer (score 0):

I was hoping to find an approach similar to debugging Asp.Net/SOAP in older versions of VS where the MSTest engine would start the IISExpress and attach VS to the Asp.Net projects. Edit and continue was supported.

I have worked out the following approaches, so far:

RestSharp Code:

```
    var url = $"http://localhost:7071/api";
    var functionKey = "this value is ignored by 'Azure Functions Core Tools' ";

    var client = new RestSharp.RestClient(url);
    var request = new RestSharp.RestRequest("GetConnectionString", RestSharp.Method.POST);
    request.AddHeader("x-functions-key", functionKey);

    var response = client.Execute<string>(request);
```

- Option 1:

Run 2nd instance of VS and run the Functions.

Update code to reflect url paths displayed by ***Azure Functions Core Tools.***

Edit and continue  works.

- Option 2:

Add this class to UnitTest project:

Attach to func.exe process to debug functions

Edit and continue do not work.

```
   [TestClass]
    public class Initializer
    {
        static System.Diagnostics.Process process { get; set; }

        [AssemblyInitialize]
        public static void Initialize(TestContext context)
        {
            //process does not use the WorkingDirectory properly with %userprofile%
            var userprofile = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.UserProfile);
            var path = $@"{userprofile}\source\repos\mypro\...\myproj.Functions\bin\Debug\netcoreapp3.1";

            var startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo
            {
                FileName = @"cmd.exe",
                Arguments = @"/C ""%localappdata%\AzureFunctionsTools\Releases\3.2.0\cli_x64\func.exe host start --port 7071 --pause-on-error""",
                //RedirectStandardInput = true,
                //RedirectStandardOutput = true,
                //RedirectStandardError = true,
                //UseShellExecute = false,

                UseShellExecute = true,
                WorkingDirectory = path
            };

            process = new System.Diagnostics.Process()
            {
                StartInfo = startInfo

            };
            process.Start();

       //     Thread.Sleep(3000);

        }

    [AssemblyCleanup]
    public static void Cleanup()
    {
        process.CloseMainWindow();
    }
}
```

- Option 3:

Start func.exe process

Working Folder: ...\source\repos\xxx\xxx\xxx.Functions\bin\Debug\netcoreapp3.1\

Command Line:

```
"C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\AzureFunctionsTools\Releases\3.2.0\cli_x64\func.exe" host start --port 7071 --pause-on-error
```

Attach to func.exe process.

Edit and continue does not work.